# Multiple for loops executing at the same time? Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading

Basically I am creating a game that spawns a ball after a certain amount of time has passed. However, as time goes on and the player score increases, balls that are more difficult to kill will spawn. 
Prior to this, all the spawn methods I have set in place function as I would like them to, but they were contained in a switch statement that calculated the probability a ball would spawn.

```
//pseudo:
let spawnProbability = arc4random_uniform(100)
switch spawnProbability {
    case 0…60: //60% spawn chance
        //spawn small ball
    case 61…90: //~30% spawn chance
        //spawn medium ball
    case 91…100: //~9% chance
        //spawn large ball
    default:
        break
}
```

This worked as a plan B, but I'd like to implement what I originally had designed which was the method described above.

My thought process to accomplish what I originally had in mind is:

- for loop that spawns small balls until the score counter reached a certain amount
- after the score counter reached, say, 100pts, another for loop would be executed in addition to the first loop. So, medium and small balls spawn after a delay.
- after the score counter reached another mark, large balls would begin to spawn on top of medium balls and small balls.

Here's what I mean: (pseudocode again)

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //delay
    //spawn small ball
}

if score >= 100 {
    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        //delay
        //spawn medium ball

    }
}
// . . . and so on
```

I've put alot of thought into how I could accomplish what I want but I can't come up with a better approach to this problem. I understand why this isn't working and why multiple for loops can't be executed with delay in the same class at the same time (or maybe they can and I'm just going about it in the wrong way) but I'm stuck in the sense that I don't know a better way to implement the spawn technique that I want.. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Which version of swift are you using? Threading tasks changed **a lot** between v2.3 and v3

Comment: eek lol I'm using version 2.1.1. Definitely need to update and see if that answers my question

Comment: Yeah I've dived headfirst into Swift 3. Lots of improvements and changes. Even for-loop syntax has changed!

Comment: updated swift to v3, updated syntax & everything still works but both for loops arent being executed at the same time. I suppose I could try testing if the score is bigger than 100 from the original loop then if it is I could call a func (containing other for loop) but my only fear is swift executing that entire loop first and then moving on in the original loop

Comment: yeah it didn't work at all lol. no clue how to approach this

Comment: I know your question is about executing multiple for-loops *at the same time* but have you considered just using one loop with your conditions for the score **inside** of it?

Comment: I have. I contained the old spawn code inside the switch statement which was nested inside a for loop... I did find a workaround though that executes multiple for loops after a set duration using the wait(forduration: ) method.. I suppose this works for now but I can't seem to figure out why the if statement wasn't being executed :/

Comment: To me, putting your spawn code for all balls - with the corresponding if statements - would satisfy your requirements of spawning different size balls at the same time

Comment: I see what you're saying.. and it did work. I just needed higher level balls  to spawn after a certain period of time/after a score was reached and I couldnt get it to work in just one for loop

Comment: I'll post some more suggestions soon when I have time.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much!!